# Increment counter based on change in cell value

Tags: vba, excel, rows

I'm trying to put a formula that can iterate the count of windows. The `window` should increment on a change in `binary`. Ideally something like this. Given columns `id` and `binary`, `window` should increment as values in `binary` changes between 0 and 1.

**Something like this:**

[image]

Is there a formula that can solution this, or is VBA the way?

Comment: `id` seems irrelevant. Why mention it?

Comment: @pnuts That makes sense (although my question was more directed to OP).

Comment: i don't know why i was overthinking this. Thanks all i truly appreciate the simplification.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It doesn't require VBA - simply a formula copied down column 'C' (Window). Enter 1 into C2. Then, enter the following into C3, then copy and paste to the rest of the cells from C4 down in column C:

```
=IF(B2<>B3,C2+1,C2)
```